# How unmounting really works?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I observed a strange behavior in React while unmounting a component. Typically, when we unmount a component, we do this.

```
const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false)

const onKeyDown = (event) => { console.log(event) }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

    return () => { window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown) }
  }, [isVisible])

return (
    <button onClick={() => setVisibility(!isVisible)}>Click me!</button>
  )
```

It works perfectly fine, but when we try to achieve this same thing using an if-else statement instead of a return, unmounting doesn't work. I searched for the reason, and I found out that when the state changes, React re-renders the handler function, which results in mismatching of both the handler (old and new one), and it won't remove.

Code using if-else statement.

```
const [isVisible, setVisibility] = useState(false)

const onKeyDown = (event) => { console.log(event) }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(isVisible) window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

    else window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown) 
  }, [isVisible])

return (
    <button onClick={() => setVisibility(!isVisible)}>Click me!</button>
  )
```

But now my question is how it works when we write `return()`? Does React save the same handler function when we write `return()`?

Comment: Remove the `isVisible` dependency from the `useEffect` hook and it will work as expected. Right now, the hook is running every time `isVisible` changes, and you're ending up with multiple listeners. Removing the dependency lets the hook run only once on initial mount, and runs the clean up function when it unmounts.

Comment: What do you mean by _” when we try to achieve this same thing using an if-else statement instead of a return”_? Can you show your code that is using the if-statement so that we can describe the difference

Comment: @NickParsons I have added the code for the if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the answer you're looking for, but I had issues where a stateful variable was needed on my unmount function (saving a form value to localstorage), and the issue seemed to lie in the fact that the original value on initial render was being used, and would not update: (I assume because my useEffect had been set to only run at the start via ,[])

If the if/else statement you mentioned is based on a stateful variable, you likely ran into the same situation.

Here's a small code snippet of what solved things for me, the same idea likely applies for you. Just use a ref and keep the ref updated as you state value changes:

```
const formValueRef = useRef<any>();
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      saveEntryFormToLocalStorage(formValueRef.current); // save form to storage when the component is destroyed
    }
  }, []) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

useEffect(() => {
    formValueRef.current = form.values;
  }, [form.values]);   // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```